# Best practice for map of strings, override hashcode and equlas

Tags: java, hash, overriding

I'm looking for the best practice, should i override hashcode and equalse whenever i'm using map in java? or for `Map<String, String>` its not required?

Comment: Try overriding equals and hashcode for `String`. It´s not possible since the String class is declared as final. You should also only override `equals` and `hashcode` if the equals method is inherited by the object class or if your are inheriting from another object and need to compare additional information in this new class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String is an API class and you don't have access to modify, you can't even extend them since they are `final`. API have best implementation of equals and hash code implementation for them. Goahead and use them.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to if there is a good one already which is the case for `String`. In fact you can't override String's methods because it is `final`. However if you define your own class and you would like to store objects of it in a collection in general then you have to write a good `hashCode/equals` methods. Check the docs for existing types to check if they are suitable for storing in collection in general or hashing more specifically.